# How do I read square brackets in Ruby documentation

Tags: ruby, notation

How do I read this argument list? Is this two values in the argument list or just one? What does the comma inside the bracket mean?

```
  fetch( key [,default] ) -> obj
```

Comment: *Optionality is expressed by square brackets, e.g., [a]b stands for ab | b.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth_syntax_notation

Comment: @Zabba: That is true for WSN, but not necessarily true for other documentation that is not specified in Wirth Syntax Notation. However, the square brackets have indeed become an informal way of expressing an optional part of program text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anywhere on that documentation site where the notation used for argument lists is explained. However, the square brackets are frequently used to mean "optional" in programming documentation. So this means that the `fetch` method can be called with just one argument, or two. If you pass two, obviously you would need a comma. So these two calls would be valid:

```
a.fetch(k)
a.fetch(k, 5)
```

Comment: `default` here means return default value, if `k` value not found.

Comment: @Dolphin: The behaviour is explained in more detail in the [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) documentation.

Comment: @GregHewgill Just friendly comment nobody mentioned it.

Comment: @Dolphin: No worries, I just noticed that nobody had linked to the *actual* documentation page either. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some context would help here, but I believe it's saying:

"pass in key to the fetch method. If you pass in a second argument it'll be used, but there is a default value if you just pass in key"